# Email not send using Gmail smtp on host

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, gmail

I've used this code to sending emails. When I test this code in LOCALHOST, it works correctly, but in host, I get this error:

> Failure sending mail.few

My code is:

```
Dim MailMsg As New MailMessage(New Net.Mail.MailAddress("MYUSERNAME@gmail.com"), New Net.Mail.MailAddress("myname@gmail.com"))
MailMsg.Subject = "test"
MailMsg.Body = "test"
MailMsg.IsBodyHtml = True
Dim SmtpMail As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient
Dim SMTPUserInfo As New Net.NetworkCredential()
SMTPUserInfo.UserName = "MYUSERNAME"
SMTPUserInfo.Password = "MYPASSWORD"
SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = False
SmtpMail.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo
SmtpMail.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
SmtpMail.Port = 587
SmtpMail.EnableSsl = True
SmtpMail.Send(MailMsg)
```

Comment: Maybe Gmail blocks you.. Check via another server

Comment: I've used 2 Gmail accounts, but the problem still exists

Comment: @WozzeC which port? I've test the port 465 or 587 without any success.

Comment: Try another server, not gmail.. Gmail blocks it..

Comment: Is there any server like Gmail?

Comment: Does your host not supply email server?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to send Emails from my host because of the reliable and SPAM problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    'Start by creating a mail message object
    Dim MyMailMessage As New MailMessage()

    'From requires an instance of the MailAddress type
    MyMailMessage.From = New MailAddress("USERNAME@gmail.com")

    'To is a collection of  types
    MyMailMessage.To.Add("DESTINATION@EXAMPLE.COM")

    MyMailMessage.Subject = "XXXXXXX" & x
    MyMailMessage.Body = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "

    Dim attach As New Attachment(fileName)

    MyMailMessage.Attachments.Add(attach)

    'Create the SMTPClient object and specify the SMTP GMail server
    Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
    SMTPServer.Port = 587
    SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME@gmail.com", "PASSWD")
    SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
    SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage)

    SMTPServer.Dispose()

    MyMailMessage.Dispose()
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing, but I'm getting "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure” when SMPT server has a valid certificate."